# Zero in Precision and Recall in ML model Random Forest in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

How it is possible that I have 0 False Positive and 0 True Positives at my model? By doing so I have 0 in Precision and Recall, what can I do ?

[image]

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: What library are you using? What does your data look like? What model parameters are you using? This is important information. From your question it is impossible to tell, it just seems that your model predicts everything as negative.

Comment: do an analysis of the data.  Bad data is the number one reason classifiers fail